# Bound variable and sapply

Tags: r, sapply, bound-variable

I am used to use `apply` familiy functions to avoid `for` loop with R. In this context I was wondering it there is a way to avoid typing a bound variable. For example, say I want to do 100 times an operation `do.call(myfun, args)`. With `for` I'd write:

```
res = seq(100)
for(i in seq(100)){res[i] = do.call(myfun, args)}
```

with `apply` I type:

```
res = sapply(seq(100), function(i) do.call(myfun, args))
```

I understand that `sapply` tries to apply the function to one argument, it is an element of `seq(100)`, but is there a way to avoid this, because indeed this variable (here `i`) has no meaning neither utility ?

thanks for the insight

Comment: you can do `sapply(seq(100), identity)`, or any other function in place of `identity`, no need for anonymous function

Comment: yes, identity is a function taking one argument; my case is when I want to make a given calculation a given number of times, ie repeted simulation with the same parameters; for example `res = sapply(seq(100), function(i) do.call(myfun, args) )`

Comment: oh ok, you probably want `replicate`, ie `replicate(10, do.call(identity, list(1:10)))`

Comment: ok cool, as simple as that, I didn't know this function !